# how to read only certain columns from a parquet file

Tags: parquet

I would like to know how to read only certain columns from a parquet file, and selecting column names by a pattern like:
`df = spark.read.parquet("/v1/phenotypes/tabular/pheno.parquet").select("xeid","x20002_0_*")`

Of course this does not work since the wildcard * is bad syntax.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify the column names so one can see if they have any pattern which could be utilized?

Comment: Sure, the column names are: "xeid" and then all column names that start with "x20002_0_"

Comment: Is the file in spark? It seems that if you just have a simple "parquet" file, you would just use pandas.read_parquet["xeid"], after first writing a separate line with a regex to pull out the columns that match x20002_0_ as you need.  It's a quick hack :)